# Matthew's Correlation Coefficient and Precision throws errors in RandomizedSearchCV

Tags: python, scikit-learn, randomized-algorithm, make-scorer

I keep getting this error:

```
invalid value encountered in double_scalars: mcc = cov_ytyp / np.sqrt(cov_ytyt * cov_ypyp)
```

Is there something wrong with how I implemented it in a custom-scorer?

```
parameters_XG = {'n_estimators': np.arange(50, 500, 50),
                 'learning_rate':np.arange(0.1, 1.05, .05),
                 'colsample_bytree': np.arange(0.1, 1.05, .05),
                 'sub_sample': np.arange(0.5, 1.05, .05),
                 'min_child_weight': np.arange(1, 10),
                 'gamma': np.arange(0.1, 5, 0.2),
                 'max_depth': np.arange(1, 15), 
                 'scale_pos_weight': np.arange(0.1, 1.0, .05)}


XG_model = XGBClassifier(booster = 'gbtree', random_state=2504, n_jobs = -1)


multi_score = {'neg_log_loss': 'neg_log_loss',
               'precision': 'precision',
               'recall': 'recall',
               'F1_weighted': 'f1_weighted',
               'ROC_AUC': 'roc_auc',
               'Brier_score': 'brier_score_loss',
               'MCC': make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef)}
    


search_XG = RandomizedSearchCV(XG_model, parameters_XG, scoring = multi_score, 
                                n_jobs = -1, cv = cv_RSKFCV, n_iter = 200, refit = 'neg_log_loss',
                                random_state = 2504).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

**EDIT:**
I understand why it throws the warnings/errors, however what I don't understand is why now it won't fit at all? I would expect just many values to be inf/nan but currently it throws a traceback to the  `random_state = 2504).fit(X_train, y_train)` How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calculating Matthews correlation your are dividing two values. The problem you obtain is that you are dividing by 0 (difficult to deal with).

This is probably due to the model is always predicting one class (for example, TP and FP will be 0, and denominator will be 0 too). To solve it you may adjust parameters you are using in order to avoid these "silly" models that only predicts one class.

You can also avoid the Matthews correlation when doing RandomizedSearchCV, and only plot it for the final model. But of course, you will miss this score for every iteration of the model.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and it makes sense, but I would still expect it to be able to fit to the train data and just produce many inf/nans but somehow it doesn't fit at all (see edit)

Comment: @desertnaut I will accept this answer and open a new question. It is a bit strange for someone else to decide whether or not an answer actually worked: Implementation/understanding takes time. The actual error thrown here is stated (I showed the actual traceback and that's all that was produced by python for me). Nonetheless, I will accept more answer from now on.

Comment: @Oorschelp apologies if I gave the impression of "deciding" that the answer worked; it was not my intention - it was what I guessed based on your own comment and the fact that the question was actually changed, giving the impression that the initial question was somehow resolved.

Comment: @desertnaut No worries, I can see what caused the confusion. Thanks for the feedback anyway :)