# Warning that seems a bug in Matthews correlation coefficient computation

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, grid-search, gridsearchcv

The grid search part of my code looks like this:

```
svc_param_grid={"C":c, "kernel":kernel, "gamma":gamma, "degree":degree}
grid_cv_object = GridSearchCV(
    estimator=SVC(),
    param_grid=svc_param_grid,
    n_jobs=-1,
    verbose=3,
    cv=k_fold,
    # a callable that returns a single value
    scoring=make_scorer(matthews_corrcoef)
)
```

It is used for multi-class classification (predicting protein secondary structure sequence).

Why am I getting this error and is there a workaround?

```
/usr/local/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py:873: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
  mcc = cov_ytyp / np.sqrt(cov_ytyt * cov_ypyp)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matthew's Correlation Coefficient and Precision throws errors in RandomizedSearchCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65990697/matthews-correlation-coefficient-and-precision-throws-errors-in-randomizedsearc)

Comment: No, it does not. I went to the source code and whenever there is a division by zero the result is '0' instead of undetermined.

Comment: source code is here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py

Comment: Are you just receiving a warning, or is there an error you haven't posted?

That issue was reported as misleading and fixed last June. Could you post the output of `print(sklearn.__version__)`?

Comment: It's a warning, but still I want to know where it is coming from. sklearn version is 0.24.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing [this issue](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/16924), which was fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/19977), after the 0.24.2 release.

The warning is caused by a division-by-zero due to no variance in your predictions. It is misleading and can be ignored; the metric is correctly returning zero.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one question more to be sure, matthews_corrcoef can be used for multi-label classification right? I ask because I've seen people computing some average mcc (they compute matthews_corrcoef for each label and then average it) and I'm not sure why.

Comment: As discussed in the [User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#matthews-corrcoef), sklearn's mcc function uses a micro-averaging approach.

Comment: I meant to include in my previous comment - for MCC, I believe the micro-averaging approach is generally better, as the macro-averaging approach you describe - calculating the binary MCC for each class and then averaging - will penalize poor performance on a small minority class even more severely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! It makes sense :)